# In Xcode how do I add a breakpoint inside a block?

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which returns a block. I want to add a breakpoint inside the block. In Xcode adding a breakpoint on a line that's inside the block causes execution to pause when the method is returned and not when the block is executed. How do I add a breakpoint inside a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same difficulty, until I tried using Xcode 4's LLDB debugger (go to Product>Edit Scheme to turn it on). Perhaps you'll have better luck with it.

Comment: Great! Unfortunately it doesn't support iOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW8)

You can set breakpoints and single step into blocks. You can invoke a block from within a GDB session using invoke-block, as illustrated in this example:

```
$ invoke-block myBlock 10 20
```

If you want to pass in a C string, you must quote it. For example, to pass this string into the doSomethingWithString block, you would write the following:

```
$ invoke-block doSomethingWithString "\"this string\""
```

Comment: Abizem: Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. I want to pause inside a block and inspect it in the context.