# UIDocument save to URL fails?

Tags: objective-c, ios

It seems that completion handler block is never invoked. Is that means the save fails? I po `self.document.fileURL` in console, which appears valid.

```
[self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
// set breakpoint here, but it won't stop
            [[[Fetcher alloc]init] fetchImageFromSring:HTTP_REQUEST inContext:self.document.managedObjectContext];
        }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion handler block should be invoked regardless of whether the save succeeded

About the completionHandler from [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html)

> completionHandler
>   A block with code that is executed when the save operation concludes. The block returns no value and has one parameter:
>   success
>   YES if the save operation succeeds, otherwise NO.
>   This block is invoked on the calling queue.

Have you put a breakpoint on this line to make sure it runs

```
[self.document saveToURL:self.document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
```

EDIT
I believe the issue can be which type of debugger you are using. [(from this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949122/1015071)
Make sure you are using `lldb`

Even if you don't change debuggers, you could always verify the block is executed with  `NSLog(@"block is running, save successfully - %d", success)`

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint there, and it does run. Yet the line inside completion block DON'T run

Comment: @Philip007 try using NSLog or changing the debugger. If you don't know how to change the debugger, I can spell it out.

Comment: Thanks, I finally find out that `BOOL success` is just a helper variable I can use inside the completion handler block. I can use `if success == YES` to determine if the save operation succeed or fail, then handle it differently.